# What is pytorch opposite of nonzero

Tags: python, pytorch

The `nonzero` in `PyTorch` return the indexes of non-zero elements.

```
tensor([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False])
tensor([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8])
```

What is the opposite of it? To get indexes of all zeros?

Comment: `(~tensor).nonzero()`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Note that the inverse code is obtained for integers and the inverse code of all integers except -1 is not 0. For integer tensors, it will get incorrect result.

Comment: @MechanicPig - Sure, only works for similar (boolean) tensors as in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(x == 0).nonzero()
```

Simply reforming the `nonzero` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `torch.where`:

```py
import torch

a = torch.randint(2, size=(8,))
torch.where(a == 0)[0]
```

Comment: Where is problematic, since it looses the grad_fn